# Including .ply file for javascript

Tags: javascript, php, include, 3d-model

I'm using a 3d modeling javascript library to view .ply files in a web page.
I have a folder currently in my public folder which javascript can access which has a temporary .ply file that should show up if other .ply files aren't found, this works fine.

All of the other .ply files are in private storage.

I don't want to put all the .ply files I have in the public folder, but I would like to send the one when the user needs to access it.  If I just include the file using the include function it prints out the .ply file, definitely not what I want.

Is there a way I can just send the .ply file in the obj folder without actually putting the .ply file in the obj folder on the server?  Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Which JS library are you using? Three.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue really wasn't including the file like I thought, the default ply file was on a much different scale than all th eother ply files which was making it not show up.  Here is the code to include the files anyway.

$ply is the relative path to the ply file.

```
<script src={{'"'.$ply.'"'}}></script>
```

and in the javascript.

```
<?php if($ply == null){ ?>
        loader.load( '../obj/default.ply' );
<?php }else{ ?>
<?php   $ply =  str_replace ( "\\" , '/' , $ply);?>
        loader.load( {{"'../".$ply."'"}} );
<?php }?>
```